# Drawer Layout Overlapping | Covering complete space in Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Hi I am trying to implement Feed App  and implementing Navigation Drawer, Tab Layout and Recyclerview in Fragment.

**See Screenshots here :**

[Screenshot With out Drawer layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh54F.jpg)

[Screenshot of app with Drawer layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYdQL.png)

Here is my code.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.sirajm.bottomnav.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <include
            layout="@layout/content_main"
             />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_panel"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_feed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

frament_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FeedFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

   // private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                   // mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                  //  mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dashboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  //  mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.content_panel, new FeedFragment())
                .commit();

      //  mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mtext);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

FeedFragment.java

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private View rootView;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
   private TextTabsAdapter adapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FeedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }




    private void initialise() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Simple Tabs Example");
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(), drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        drawer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteColor));
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    }
    private void prepareDataResource() {

        addData(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
        addData(new FragmentTwo(), "TWO");
       // addData(new FragmentThree(), "THREE");
    }

    private void addData(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        titleList.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        initialise();
        prepareDataResource();
        adapter = new TextTabsAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList, titleList);

        // Bind Adapter to ViewPager.
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Link ViewPager and TabLayout
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

FragmentOne.java

```
class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mrecyclerview;
    private FeedsAdapter feedadapter;
    View rootView;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        mrecyclerview = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        populate();
        return rootView;
    }

public void populate(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Please wait");
        progressDialog.show();
        Call<FeedList> call = Apis.getApi().getFeedLists(101,"param");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<FeedList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FeedList> call, Response<FeedList> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                FeedList feedsdata = response.body();
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponseFeeds: "+feedsdata.getFeeds());
                FeedsStore.setFeedLists(feedsdata.getFeeds());
                feedadapter = new FeedsAdapter(feedsdata.getFeeds(),getContext());
                mrecyclerview.setAdapter(feedadapter);


            }
}
```

Everything is working fine if not adding Drawerlayout and navigation Drawer but When I am including DrawerLayout in FeedFragment then its allocating complete space. I am not where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one solved by making drawer layout as parent and coordinator layout as child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```