# Using AndroidStudio emulation On_Click Events within fragments firing when using tab and enter key but not mouse click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem within my code that seems to me as it is working but only in the given situation where On_Click Events within fragments are firing when using tab and enter key but not mouse click.  I am using the emulator through android studio SDK23 for the emulater.  When I test it on my phone sdk26 it does not allow the tap to click anything within the fragment.  I feel like I may be missing something very simple.

Here is my Activity:

```
package com.wgu.c196.testproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.wgu.c196.testproject.database.TermDatabase;
import com.wgu.c196.testproject.fragment.TestFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        TestFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener{

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private TextView fragTitle;


    public DrawerLayout getDrawer() {
        return drawer;
    }

    public void setDrawer(DrawerLayout drawer) {
        this.drawer = drawer;
    }

    public TextView getFragTitle() {
        return fragTitle;
    }

    public void setFragTitle(TextView fragTitle) {
        this.fragTitle = fragTitle;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Fragment testFragment = new TestFragment();
        replaceFragment(testFragment );


        fragTitle = findViewById(R.id.fragment_title);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        item.setChecked(true);
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        fab.show();

        switch(item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.nav_terms:

            case R.id.nav_courses:

            case R.id.nav_assessment:

            case R.id.nav_scheduler:

            case R.id.nav_alerts:

            case R.id.nav_share:

            case R.id.nav_send:

            default:
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        TermDatabase.destroyInstance();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Begin the transaction
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main_placeholder, fragment, fragment.toString());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListFragmentInteraction(View view) {

    }
}
```

My Fragment:

```
package com.wgu.c196.testproject.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.wgu.c196.testproject.MainActivity;
import com.wgu.c196.testproject.R;


public class TestFragment extends Fragment  {

    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private View mView;


    public View getView() {
        return mView;
    }

    public void setView(View mView) {
        this.mView = mView;
    }

    ragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public TestFragment() {
    }

    // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static TestFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);


        ((MainActivity) mView.getContext()).getFragTitle().setText("Test Button");

        Button btn = mView.findViewById(R.id.d_button_id);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Something clicked me in Fragment!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   }
                               });

        btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Something touched me in Fragment!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        return mView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onListFragmentInteraction(View view);
    }

}
```

My main layout  activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/global_top_margin"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/content_main_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_fragment_top_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        ></FrameLayout>



    <include layout="@layout/nav_menu_main" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_add_entity"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My fragment layout fragment_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/term_list_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/d_button_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="My Button to Click"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I fixed my own problem.  Which was started by choosing Navigation Activity when first starting my project.

I removed 
`<include layout="@layout/nav_menu_main" />` 
from my activity_main.xml then restructured it whith the xml from nav_menu_main, using DrawerLayout as the Parent and CoordinatorLayout from activity_main.xml as the child.

I consulted this stack Overflow which lead me to my fix.

[Drawer Layout Overlapping | Covering complete space in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46874830/drawer-layout-overlapping-covering-complete-space-in-fragment)

My new activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/global_top_margin"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/content_main_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_fragment_top_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_add_entity"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```